# Microsoft Azure Recovery Services (MARS) agent versions - how to create a version report

Tags: azure, powershell

I have to prepare a report contains list of all on-prem hosts which have MARS agent installed and set backup in cloud. some agents are outdated and I have to hind ones.

For one recovery service vault it was simple in the GUI, because
For

is there a possibility to get it from command line?
For GUI, when we had one single Recovery Service Vault one look was fine. It shows protected server nasme and version. Find outdated agent and plan upgrade was easy and nobody care about sript it...

```
$vaults = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault 
foreach ($vault in $vaults)
{
# $vault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -ResourceGroupName "resourceGroup" -Name "vaultName"
$Container = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType Windows -VaultId $vault.ID
$BackupItem = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $Container -WorkloadType AzureFiles -VaultId $vault.ID 
}
```

return nothing :/

Comment: Why would it return anything? You’re simply capturing to variables. Have you tried inspecting the variables?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `-WorkloadType` from *"**AzureFiles**"* to ***"AzureVM"*** worked for me as backup created for the item type `VM`.

*I tried same script in my environment and worked as follows.*

```
$vaults = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault 
foreach ($vault in $vaults)
{
$vault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>" -Name "xxxxvault"
$Container = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType AzureVM -VaultId $vault.ID
$BackupItem = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $Container -WorkloadType AzureVM -BackupManagementType xxx -VaultId $vault.ID 
}
```

***Output:***

[image]
[image]

*You can add* `-BackupManagementType` *as per the requirements*.
(Eg: MARS)